# What does packagingOptions -> pickFirst do?

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

In a ReactNative application, I can see inside the android/app/build.gradle the following section:

```
android {
...
   packagingOptions {
       pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
   }
...
}
```

What does that do?

I am trying to understand what happens each time a "pickFirst" is added there